# Convert json String to object when square brackets are missing in java

Tags: json, spring, jackson

I am trying to parse a json string mentioned below,

```
"inventoryItems":{"fare":"299.00","ladiesSeat":"false","passenger":{"address":"xxx,Bangalore","age":"26","email":"xxxxxxxxx@gmial.com","gender":"MALE","idNumber":"123ABC","idType":"PAN_CARD","mobile":"9999999999","name":"abcd","primary":"true","title":"Mr"},"seatName":"27"}
```

The structure is there is an **inventoryItems** which is an **array** and inside that there is an **passenger** **array**, The problem is there are **no square braces**, **since the array contains only one value in both inventoryItems and passenger**. This malformed data is from a third party server so I cant correct them. While converting this to Object **Jackson library** is throwing an excception.

**My question is how to form a proper json string with square braces from the above so that jackson is able to convert it into java object?**

Comment: Maybe the [DeserializationFeature](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html) ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY solves your problem (via [ObjectMapper.enable(...)) without converting the string?

Comment: I have added an answer with my solution so you may mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [DeserializationFeature](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html) ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY should solve your problem (via [ObjectMapper.enable(...)) without a conversion of the string.